# Редирект на текущую страницу после выполнения View в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть несколько разных страниц содержащих одинаковую ссылку, которая ведет на вьюху. Вьюха в конце своей работы должна добавить сообщение в messages и редиректнуться обратно на ту страницу, на которой нажали ссылку. Как лучше всего это сделать?

Можно конечно передавать адрес, с которого был совершен переход в параметре. Но как-то это колхозненько, может есть вариант получше?

Пример вьюхи для понятности:

```py
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import messages

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        msg = 'Это сообщение выведется на той странице, с которой \ 
               произошел переход'

        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, msg)
        return redirect(path_to_my_page_or_view_name)
```

Comment: определить предыдущую страницу

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 а как?

Comment: request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')

Comment: Насколько помню, `request` содержит данные об истории переходов

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете получить предыдущую страницу с помощью:

```
request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/